# Is there a standard hole diameter for corner braces?

Tags: bolts, measuring, brackets

I'm planning a project that requires corner braces, and I want to figure out what size bolts I can put through them. Unfortunately, at least on the Home Depot website, the corner brace product listings do not list the hole diameters, though they do have the length and width of the brace.

Is there a standard hole diameter for corner braces? Or is there, perhaps, a standard hole diameter for each width of corner brace? If not, other than by going to the store and measuring, is there a way to know how large the holes are?

Comment: 1" or 12" braces? There is a huge range of brace and screw/bolt sizes. Also, different braces/uses/wall materials require different screws/bolts and differnent fasteners. What are the particulars of your project?

Comment: @bib, I'm looking at 2" or shorter braces, and I want to put bolts through them and through 2x4s. The goal is to temporarily join two 2x4s with the 1.5" face of one resting against the 3.5" face of the the other, using a bracket on the inside of the join (hence maximum 2"). I want to use bolts rather than screws to make it easier to detatch and re-attach.

Comment: Sites like HD often have a question and answer feature that the manufacturer monitors and answers questions on.  You may want to check if the particular product page you're looking for has such a feature. That way you can get an exact answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no standard sizes.

Braces of the type you are considering most commonly have holes that are less than 1/4" and more than 1/8", somewhere around 3/16".  They are usually intended for #6, #8 or #10 screws. You could probably use 1/8" bolts, or maybe 3/16" depending on the brace. 1/4" bolts probably won't fit unless you ream out the holes.

Which bolts will be sufficient depends on how much strain will be on them and how many braces you are using.